# Proper Formatting for Adjusting a Pandas DF in a Function

Tags: python, pandas

New programmer here. I have a pandas dataframe that I adjust based on certain if conditions. I use functions to adjust the values when certain if conditions are met. I use functions because if the function is used in multiple spots, its easier to go adjust the function code once rather than making the same adjustment several times in different spots in the code. My question focuses on what is considered best practice when making these functions.

So I have included four sample functions below. The first sample function works, but i'm wondering if its considered poor practice to structure it like that and instead use one of the other variations. Please let me know what is considered 'proper' and if you have any other input. As a quick side note, I will only ever be using one 'dataframe.' Otherwise I would have passed the dataframe as an input at the very least.

Thank you!

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame #Some dataframe

#version 1 simplest
def adjustdataframe():
    dataframe.iat[0,0] = #Make some adjustment

#version 2 return dataframe
def adjustdataframe():
    dataframe.iat[0,0] = #Make some adjustment
    return dataframe

#version 3 pass df as input but don't explicitly return df
def adjustdataframe(dataframe):
    dataframe.iat[0, 0] =  # Make some adjustment

#version 4 pass df as input and return df
def adjustdataframe(dataframe):
    dataframe.iat[0, 0] =  # Make some adjustment
    return dataframe
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell since this code is so abstract. Can you be more specific, maybe provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I think it wouldn't be proper to use *version 1* and *version 2* in your python code because *normally** it would throw an `UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment` error. For example, try running this code:

```py
def version_1():
    """ no parameters & no return statements """
    nums = [num**2 for num in nums]


def version_2():
    """ no parameters """
    nums = [num**2 for num in nums]
    return nums


nums = [2,3]
version_1()
version_2()
```

---

Versions *3 and 4* are good in this regard since they introduce parameters, but the third function wouldn't change anything (it would change your local variable within a function but the adjustments *wouldn't* take place globally since they never leave a local scope).

```py
def version_3(nums):
    """ no return """
    nums = [num**2 for num in nums] # local variable

nums = [2,3] # global variable
version_3(nums)
# would result in an error
assert version_3(nums) == [num**2 for num in nums]
```

Since *version 4* has a return statement, the adjustments made within a local scope *would* take place.

```py
def version_4(nums):
    nums = [num**2 for num in nums]
    return nums

new_nums = version_4(nums)
assert new_nums == [num**2 for num in nums]

# but original `nums` was never changed
nums
```

So, I believe `version_4` to be the best practice.

---

*normally - in terms of general python functions; with `pandas` objects, it's different: all four functions will result in a variable specifically called `dataframe` being changed *in place* (which you wouldn't want to do usually):

```py
def version_1():
    dataframe.iat[0,0] = 999 

def version_2():
    dataframe.iat[0,0] = 999 
    return dataframe

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"values" : [1,2,3,4,5]})
version_1()
dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"values" : [1,2,3,4,5]})
version_2()
dataframe
```

Both of the functions would throw `NameError` if your variable is called differently; try running your first or second function without defining `dataframe` object beforehand (use `df` as a variable name for example):

```py
# restart your kernel - `dataframe` object was never defined
df = pd.DataFrame({"values" : [1,2,3,4,5]})
version_1()
version_2()
```

With `version_3` and `version_4`, you'd expect different results.

```py
def version_3(dataframe):
    dataframe.iat[0, 0] = 999

def version_4(dataframe):
    dataframe.iat[0, 0] = 999 
    return dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({"values" : [1,2,3,4,5]})
version_3(df) 
df

df = pd.DataFrame({"values" : [1,2,3,4,5]})
version_4(df)
df
```

But the results are the same: your original dataframe will be changed in place.

To avoid it, don't forget to make a copy of your dataframe:

```py
def version_4_withcopy(dataframe):
    df = dataframe.copy()
    df.iat[0, 0] = 999 
    return df

dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"values" : [1,2,3,4,5]})
new_dataframe = version_4_withcopy(dataframe)
dataframe
new_dataframe
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to provide such a detailed answer. This is great!

Comment: Quick side question. You say you don't usually want to make inplace changes with dataframes. Do you say this because people are mostly using pandas to conduct data analysis and they very rarely want to change the source data, while doing temporary analysis? I'm guessing my program might be the exception, since the only output I care about is the ending dataframe. (I effectively have a file filled with CSVs that I read into pandas and this program outputs the adjusted dataframes to a different 'output file' also in CSV format. The source csv is never overwritten.)

Comment: @Whip, I meant that even if you have one dataframe, you might want to make some changes to it (new columns, text cleaning etc) -and you might want to store the results as a separate variable. 
It's not obvious that without copying original dataframe beforehand, it will be changed. 

If you don't care about it then it's fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Best wishes.